# To get the month based on date

Tags: date, db2

If the days are less than 15 th of current month then I should get Current month ,  and after 15 th the. On the should roll to next month.

I m using db2 db

Comment: Please reword your question as what you have currently doesn't make sense. Also provide details about what you have tried to solve/debug your issue.

Comment: Please take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page, it will help you create a better question which in turn will increase your chances to get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
select case when day(current date)<15 then month(current date) else month(current date + 1 month) end from your table
```